# MrIbrahim Ibrahi

Tags: past-perfect

A: Was Tom there when you arrived?
B: yes he had already there

I had just got home when Kate phoned.

I had been at my mother's house.

Is this the correct grammar.

Comment: Finally, a question with a creative headline. I was getting so bored of these typical "3 uses of present perfect" and "the vs a" titles

Comment: What meaning do you want to convey? Grammar can be "correct" but still not carry the meaning you want.

Comment: @Mr.PastProgressive - not a helpful comment. Possibly you are being sarcastic? The title is a very bad one, and may help attract close votes.

Comment: It didn't mention if it was good or bad, I only stated it was a creative one and I still stand by my point. I also provided an answer for his question, as you may see below

Answer (score 2):

Was Tom there when you arrived?
possible correct answers:

yes, he **had** already **arrived** there (correct)

yes, he **was** already there (correct)

yes, he already **arrived** (correct only in spoken American English)

2nd question:

1. I **had** just **got** home when Kate phoned - (correct)
2. I just **got** home when Kate phoned (correct in spoken American English)
3. I **got/had got** home **and/after that/ then** Kate phoned (correct)
4. I **got/had got** home **before** Kate phoned (**got** and **had got** are both correct if you use before here)

"**had been** at my mother's house" = "I **was** at my mother's house before "I came home" and "Kate phoned""
In Spoken English you can say either of them, but your teacher would probably expect "had been"